# Overload toString for both Unicode and ANSI

Tags: c++, unicode, overloading

When implementing the the `toString()` function for a class should I implement both the unicode and ascii versions?

```
class MyClass
{
public:

    string toString()
    {
        return "foo";
    }

    // Should the unicode version be implemented aswell?
    wstring toString()
    {
        return L("foo");
    }

};


// Does this suffice?
#ifndef UNICODE
typedef string tstring;
#else
typedef wstring tstring;
#endif

class MyClass
{
public:

    tstring toString()
    {
        return "foo";
    }
};
```

Also is there a function overload to convert to int?

```
class MyClass
{
public:

    // ???
    int operator>>(MyClass& obj)
    {
        return myInt;
    }
private:
    int myInt;
};
```

Comment: Your first code won't compile, because the return type can't be the only difference between functions. About your second code, if you need Unicode, why bother with a non-unicode version at all? Don't start that t-stuff again... And the third, `operator int()` without shift?

Comment: ...maybe you should split this in three questions. Btw. it's ANSI, not ANSII.

Comment: Depends on how you are going to use this code. If this is just used internally, simply use `typedef std::basic_string<TCHAR> tstring` and the appropriate `_T()` macro. This solves the problem you haven't asked about: You cannot overload methods based on their return type only.

Comment: @deviantfan: It's not "ANSI" either. It's just a narrow character string. And for that matter, `wchar_t` isn't Unicode; it's just a wide character.

Comment: @NicolBolas The thing about ANSI was only about the spelling in the title, not about the content of any variable, any charset nor (not-)guarantees of any standard. The "American National Standards Institute" doesn't have two I, that's all. And I never said that wchar_t implies Unicode.

Comment: In practice `wchar_t` implies Unicode. I'd be very interested in any counter-example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Clearly this question is about Windows programming, although that's not reflected in the (current as I'm writing this) tags.

For Windows you should use the `wchar_t` type and not bother with maintaining compatibility with early Windows versions that you <sup>(1)</sup>can't even produce an executable for with modern Visual C++.

That's about it.

---

<sup><sup>(1)</sup> And if you *could* produce a Windows 9x executable, then the way to support that old Windows would not be to use archaic `T` stuff or ANSI text directly, but to use Microsoft's Layer for Unicode from the year 2000, which is now 15 years back; it's very old hat this.</sup>

Comment: You are ignoring, that restrictions to support/use MBCS or ANSI character encodings may be driven by factors other than the OS (e.g. libraries in use, maintenance of old software that cannot easily be ported to use Unicode, authoring a library that must support ANSI, etc.). Going for Unicode may be the right decision, for new code, that doesn't have any legacy restrictions. The blanket statement, however, is wrong.

Comment: @IInspectable: No, I'm not ignoring the legacy code issue; it's just not relevant for the OP's issue. It's the same for e.g. recommending a programming language. There's lots of legacy COBOL code out there, and when that's relevant it can be most important, but ordinarily one would not recommend COBOL for anything. Legacy code generally also requires legacy tooling and legacy systems testing. It's a very difficult road.

Comment: The OP doesn't state, whether this is new code, or part of an existing system. Assuming there aren't any restrictions is just as wrong as assuming the opposite. You should have posted a comment to clarify that, instead of going off on a limb and post an answer based on assumptions.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf What is 'Microsoft's Layer for Unicode from the year 2000'? Is this `TCHAR`, `LPTSTR`, etc.?

Comment: @JakeM: I googled it for you :) And no, it's not `T` stuff. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Layer_for_Unicode